# One item not aligning with CSS positioning (but all others are)

Tags: css

All my html elements are being positioned where I want them, except one, and I can't see why it should be the exception. The css snipped to exclude non relevant parts is:

```
body {
position:relative;
}

ul {
position:absolute;
list-style:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

li: {
position: relative;
top: 90px;
display: block;
height: 80px;
}

#track_title {
    position:absolute;
    top: 1px;   
    left: 80px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

<ul>
<li>
<img src="image.png">
<h2 id = "track_title">Title</h2>
<h3 id = "artist_name">Name</h3>
```

However as you can see from the screenshot the Title is appearing more than 1px from the top of its parent li. What am I doing incorrectly?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are default margins and padding for h2 & h3 element. You should set it with your fixed values.